# Error in Masterpage

Tags: asp.net, sql, master-pages

When I use this code in my master page, it can’t be debugged. But before this, which I didn't use master page, it perfectly worked.  Is there something wrong with my code? I put my code here  for your reference. Appreciate very much.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="User.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_User" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder4" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder5" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="User.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_User" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder4" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder5" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<p>
This is a list of user in a database.</p>
<p><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Edit,update and delete User accounts in asp.net membership</title>
<style type="text/css">
.GridviewDiv {font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 
Verdana, Arial, Helevetica, sans-serif; color: #303933;}
Table.Gridview{border:solid 1px #df5015;}
.Gridview th{color:#FFFFFF;border-right-color:#abb079;border-bottom-
 color:#abb079;padding:0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;text-align:center}
.Gridview td{border-bottom-color:#f0f2da;border-right-color:#f0f2da;padding:0.5em 0.5em 
0.5em 0.5em;}
.Gridview tr{color: Black; background-color: White; text-align:left}
:link,:visited { color: #DF4F13; text-decoration:none }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="GridviewDiv">
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" CssClass="Gridview"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
onrowcancelingedit="gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit"
onrowdeleting="gvDetails_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gvDetails_RowEditing"
onrowupdating="gvDetails_RowUpdating">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" ReadOnly="true"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html></p>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Why does it gives me error? I cant figure it out.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Any stacktrace?

Comment: post your master page code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have place the

`<form id="form1" runat="server">`

inside a place holder, together with a full page other tags, like the `head`

I think that this is your error here, the wrong use of place holders. Probably you have one more `form` on the master page that the one is break the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You can't have placeholders, forms and the html tag inside a p tag.